# can't find wifi networks until computer is rebooted

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I recently bought a new pc, I was able to customize my pc to include a wireless adapter, the name of the adapter is `broadcom 802.11ac network adapter`.

At first bootup my computer installed everything successfully, I then ran `windows update` to see if there were any other updates available, I recall there were, but can't remember what those were, but coming from windows update they should be alright.

Now, everytime (except that first time) I start my computer, my network adapter can't find any available wifi networks to connect to, it does not matter how many times I switch it on/off or disable/enable adapter in device manager.

I've tried updating drivers from the device manager, but it says that "*you already have the best drivers for this device*" or something like that.

I will only be able to find available wifi networks **after my computer is rebooted**, so my process is to start computer, then at login screen see if there are any networks (never is) and then just press "restart", the computer restarts and networks will show.

What could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a problem with your network card's device driver.

You mentioned you already checked for newer drivers through Device Manager. However, checking for driver updates through Device Manager only shows drivers that the manufacturer has provided to Microsoft. Often these are stable, but not the latest drivers.

Newer drivers may be available directly from the device manufacturer. You should try any that are available as this is probably a device-specific issue.